# Stability of alpha vs beta anomer in glucose

Tags: carbohydrates

As per my knowledge, there seems to be 2 main factors influencing the stability of alpha vs beta anomers of glucose:

1. H - bonding

- Considering this, beta anomer would be more stable due to the possible h bond between c1 - oh and c6 - oh

2. Anomeric effect

- I havent been taught anything much about this, all i know is that more electronegative substituents(like oh) would prefer an axial arrangement which the alpha anomer has.
- additionally i have read somewhere that hyperconjugation seems to play a role in making the alpha anomer more stable(no explaination was given) as well(I will try to mention the source as soon as possible, im unable to remember where i read that as of this moment)

My question is of two parts:

1. Ultimately, which anomer is more stable and why?
2. Does hyperconjugation actually play a role in differentiating their stabilities and how?